# 802.11 sniffering with NDIS

Tags: ieee-802.11

Is it possible to implement NDIS filter driver to catch and analyse raw 802.11 packets?
If not, then how I can catch baecon, auth and death packets in windows?

Comment: Software development is, sadly, off-topic here.

Comment: My reading may be wrong, but this isn't a development question, rather a question about the ability to use NDIS drivers on Windows to capture 802.11 traffic.

Comment: how to use a software library is software dev.. you'll get a better answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no you cannot do so in Windows with any normal drivers.

There are products that provide their own custom drivers that will allow you to capture 802.11 traffic, but product recommendations are specifically off topic.

Keep in mind when looking at products that you find a solution that best meets your needs. For instance, if you are running an 802.11ac four spatial stream network, you wouldn't want a capture solution for 802.11n two spatial stream. While it may be better than no solution, there will be traffic it won't be able to capture...but sometimes the capabilities of the network outpace the capabilities of the tools you can use.